# HTML5 Geolocation in user registration

Tags: registration, privacy, geolocation

I have sign-up page on startup, where user should provide his location - Country, State/Region and City. This is necessary information in user wants to use our service.

Question is, how user will react to browsers geolocation request?
(If he allows it, location fields will fill up automatically.)

I'm afraid user will deny request, or even worse, leave page because of privacy concerns. Is there any research about this html5 geolocation usage?

Comment: How important is it to you?  You could just ask for timezone if you're worried about privacy concerns.

Comment: Can you provide more context as to what the app does and how it's using location data?

Answer (score 2):

I would not automatically request their location.  In addition to the privacy concerns you have, some amount of users will not access your site from their "home" location (at work, on their mobile, etc.), and they'll be forced to delete and re-enter information about their home city.

Instead, maybe consider a "Use My Current Location" button near the form that will trigger the geolocation request and auto-fill fields.

Answer (score 1):

Why not ask for zipcode (or equivalent in your country)? Then you can extrapolate all of the other information from this data..

I agree with @Adam Hart, though, if you want use geolocation a button is better than automatically asking on page load.

Best UX in my opinion: Form with two initial options (zipcode input or button that asks for geolocation (as in @Adam Hart's answer)). Either selection will pre-fill rest of the form data (country, state, etc), then user moves to the next thing.